# Где поставить тире, а где — запятую?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

**Крым Россия это сила это родина моя.**

Comment: Предложите свои варианты.

Comment: Крым - Россия - это сила, это родина моя

Answer (score 2):

Такой вариант возможен, но я бы написала так:

**КрЫм, РоссИя  – это сила, это родина моя!**

Так мне кажется выразительнее и больше подходит к "родине".  Также при дефисном написании сочетание имеет одно основное ударение, а не два.

В то же время всё зависит от того, было ли раньше использовано дефисное написание Крым-Россия. Если да, то ваш вариант верный.

Comment: Спасибо большое